# Flow of token refreshing using JWT on Laravel Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, lumen

I'm building my first API with JWT. I'm using this boilerplate project: https://github.com/krisanalfa/lumen-jwt

I managed to make it work well, but I'm having a big problem: the user token expires after some time, logging the user off the application. I've read on the documentation of the project to call **/api/auth/refresh** to refresh the token, but right now it seems to me that it has two major drawbacks:

1) You have to make a single call to the API just to refresh the token, I would imagine that you would have to set up a timer to call it every X minutes (time of token expiration).

2) If the user turns off the computer for 3 hours, when he turns it back on, the token will already have expired, rendering the refresh unusable, and logging the user off.

Since I'm new to this, am I missing something? How can I make the token refresh cycle work without these drawbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your two points.

**1)** You can make an token valid for only a single use, but using blacklist feature. This however isn't entirely necessary.

In my own project, I gave tokens a 5 minute expiry, but I also applied the `jwt-refresh` middleware to my authenticated routes (wrapped in a route group), so that a new token was returned with every request.

**2)** You can also specify a refresh expiry, which is the window during which an expired token can be authenticated. This is usually much longer than a token. I used 14 days.

Therefore, if a user leaves your website for 3 hours and comes back, their token will have expired. But your app should attempt to refresh that token in the background and then re-attempt the original request.

Give some thought to the obvious security implications of the respective token lifetimes. 5 minutes is a short window for abuse, but if an expired token can be refreshed for up to 14 days, that increases the risk, unless you're blacklisting it.

Comment: I'm trying to do that, but apparently Dingo is checking for token validity when I call for a Refresh, and I still get the message: "Token Expired". Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: It's because the refresh route `api.auth.refresh` is within the `api.auth` middleware group. So the middleware is checking for validity before it reaches the controller route. If you move it outside of that, it may work.

Comment: I'm using the jwt.refresh middleware, works great on the first request, then I can't read the new token on the response. When I do console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders()); it doesn't show the token, just shows "Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate". Any idea how to read it?

Comment: more details about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334805/jwt-api-with-laravel-cant-read-token-refresh-header-on-the-client

Comment: @raphadko - you need to look at the source code for the project you're using. The new token is included in the [body response](https://github.com/krisanalfa/lumen-jwt/blob/develop/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php#L129). You can change it to a header if you want.